# How to configure Windows Server 2016 to work with Glassfish as a web server?

Tags: windows-server-2016, glassfish-4.1

I need to migrate my Glassfish 4.1 from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2016.

I've copied the Glassfish folder and pasted it in the new Windows Server 2016, but it is working only locally (http://localhost:80/myWebApp); if I try to access myWebApp via browser through another computer (http://172.29.13.228:80/myWebApp), it doesn't work.

After adding the [Web Server feature](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Identity-Manager/3.2/com.vmware.wsp-resource/GUID-A16C8A91-D3F6-44B8-BCA4-A81D1BE1D122.html) (using the Server Manager), then I can access normally a IIS page via browser, which means the web server is working; but it still doesn't work when I try to access the Glassfish.

Does anyone knows what feature to add or what to configure in the Windows Server to get access to the Glassfish ?

Answer (score 0):

I've researched and find out that I just needed to create a rule on the firewall on Windows Server and give permission on desired ports, there's no need to add any Windows web server feature.